# Why does the doomguy shooting at the wall kill enemies?

Tags: doom-2

In this very long video, the player shoots rockets at a wall, and it does damage to monsters.

What's going on here? Which bug/feature is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doom 1 and 2 are not truly 3D.  All the game physics and hit detection assumes everything is at the same height, even if it looks like it's not.  So even though there is a large total distance between the enemies, most of that distance is vertical.  The horizontal distance is very small, so the enemies are still within the blast radius.